# Is it possible for a cambelt / plug change to affect the exhaust sound of the exhaust

Tags: exhaust, timing-belt, pajero, montero

A mechanic just completed a major service (cambelt tensioner, and plugs) on my 3.5L V6 Montero/Pajero engine.
The vehicle now produces a very different exhaust sound. Before it produced an amazing sound especially when reaching high RPM's, but now it sounds close to nothing like it did before.

Otherwise running fine.

Would changing a cambelt + plugs have such a pronounced effect on the exhaust sound?
*The mechanic did note the plug gaps were very wide before.*

Vehicle: 2001 Pajero 3.5v6, 186,000KMs,

Comment: If the cam timing was correct before and after the change, you shouldn't notice anything from that. There is a chance the change in plug gap might cause a difference, but I doubt it would be anything overly noticeable. I guess stranger things happen.